# Couchbase SubDocument API for android

Tags: android, couchbase

I want to develop an android app to change the content of a document from what [this](https://blog.couchbase.com/subdocument-couchbase-java-sdk/)  tutorial says:

```
DocumentFragment<Lookup> result = bucket
.lookupIn("subdoc")
.get("sub.value")
.exists("fruits")
.exists("sub.foo")
.execute();

String subValue = result.content("sub.value", String.class);
boolean fruitsExist = result.content("fruits", Boolean.class);
boolean fooExist = bucket.exists("sub.foo");

System.out.println(subValue + ", " +
  fruitsExist + ", " +
  foExist);
```

but android does not recognize  **Lookup** symbol.

1-does SubDocument API exist for android?

2-does Couchbase Server API exist for android?

Comment: duplicated question https://forums.couchbase.com/t/subdocument-api-for-android/16288/2

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the forum post:

```
The Android API is provided by Couchbase Lite and doesn’t necessarily have the same featureset. You may want to post to the Couchbase Lite category to inquire about this. It has a bit of a different API, and I don’t think SubDocument is supported there, but there may be an alternative approach.
```